# Qual a diferença entre as property em css, background-origin e background-clip?

Tags: css3

Bom eu sei que para que serve as duas propriedades mas eu não sei a diferença entre as duas pois ambas utilizam os mesmos valores e contém os mesmos resultados no viewport!

Answer (score 2):

Compare esses exemplos: [background-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/background-origin) e [background-clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)

Note que o `background-origin` define a **posição** da imagem, e o `background-clip` **até onde** ela pode se **estender**.

- O `background-origin` funciona apenas com imagens, enquanto background-clip trabalha também com cores.
- O `background-origin`, quando utilizado sem a propriedade `background-repeat: no-repeat`, faz a imagem preencher o elemento todo, o que não acontece caso você use o `background-clip`, onde ele sim controla até onde é preenchido.
- Há um valor de atributo mutualmente exclusivo do `background-clip` chamado `text`, que faz a imagem/cor "se estender" dentro do texto apenas (como no exemplo).

Provavelmente não são só essas as diferenças, só citei algumas que notei. Essas diferenças são mais notáveis quando você utiliza eles em elementos em vez de todo o corpo da página.

Recomendo ler essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753900/is-there-any-difference-between-background-clip-and-background-origin) de outra pergunta, que faz comparações com os valores dos atributos.

Comment: valeu deu uma boa ideia

Answer (score -3):

O background-origin seta onde o seu background irá começar.
Ele pode começar a partir da sua borda, do seu padding ou da sua "content-box".

O background-clip é como se fosse uma tesoura, se definirmos seu valor para "content-box", apenas o que estava no content-box é o que será mostrado.

> > [Exemplos - Foto normal & Clip & Origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DASYX.png)

[Site para ver a diferença entre as duas propriedades](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/css-background-clip-vs-background-origin-properties-e2a15d5d7fa0)

[Arquivo .md do meu github onde eu explico melhor](https://github.com/FireguiQueen/Discover-Rocketseat/blob/main/Trilha%20fundamentar/Ex023%20(CSS%20-%20background).md)

Comment: Esta informação é importante também..: 

"background-clip" — permite definir em que área o plano de fundo deve ser exibido, o fundo fora da área será "recortado".. 
----

"background-origin" — define apenas a posição inicial do background, não temos o poder de definir mais nada (por exemplo: onde termina) usando essa propriedade por conta própria